# LEGO stormtrooper pauldron dimensions

Tags: piece-information, star-wars, customization, size

Does anyone know what the size dimensions for [Imperial](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48431pb05&name=Minifig,%20Armor%20Pauldron%20Cloth%20with%20Black%20Neck%20and%202%20Black%20Circles%20Pattern&category=%5BMinifig,%20Body%20Wear%5D#T=C) and [First Order](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb673pb01&name=Minifig,%20Armor%20Pauldron%20Cloth%20with%20Dark%20Red%20Shoulder%20Pattern&category=%5BMinifig,%20Body%20Wear%5D#T=C&C=11) pauldrons are? I want to make some custom ones.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this information from Brick Owl, the Imperial pauldron would fit in a rectangle of dimensions 2.7 x 2.3 centimeters. The center hole on all capes must be able to clear the neck diameter of approximately 4.88 mm as was quoted [here](http://www.bzpower.com/board/topic/5866-needed-part-measurements/) backed up by my own measurements.

If you are looking to make a pauldron for yourself, you might consider finding a trace of the desired pauldron and adjusting the scale until the image is 2.7 cm at the widest. Making a 5 mm hole will suffice so the piece does not fall too low on the shoulders. Hope this helps.